# Protect Logo in Excel sheet that is protected with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**Intro**
I have an Excel form that the cells highlighted blue in the attached screen-shot are protected via VBA, and the yellow cells are editable.

The reason I have a VBA protection is to allow deleting of entire row(s) while Column 5 and Column 7 are protected (and some other features which the Excel built in Sheet Protection feature doesn't not allow).

**Challenge**
How do I protect the Logo with VBA, to disable the option of moving/resizing/deleting it.

I've looked in many of the experts forums before, but didn't a solution with VBA.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Worksheet.Protect method definition:
[image]
you will see that the second parameter (DrawingObjects) is the one you are after.

A quick example:

```
Sub DemoProtect()
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet: Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    '
    mySheet.Protect Password:="test", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True
End Sub
```

You can read the full help on Microsoft Docs: [Worksheet.Protect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect)

You also need to keep in mind that a Shape can have the following "move" options:
[image]

The `Locked` checkbox must be on as well.

This is important because you might want to be able to resize the rows and columns by setting the `AllowFormattingColumns` and `AllowFormattingRows` parameters of the `.Protect` method so you need to decide if the shape moves and resizes with the range it sits on by setting one of the 3 options inside the **Format Shape** box.

Comment: not what I meant, I know hot to access the protect object in VBA, was looking to accomplish this another way. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: @ShaiRado Have you read the full answer? You can only prevent the move/resize/delete if the Sheet and Objects are protected and if you set the ```AllowFormattingColumns``` and ```AllowFormattingRows``` to ```False``` when protecting if the shape properties are set to Locked and Move and Size with cells. If set to Dont't move or size with cells then you don't care about protecting row/column formats. Have you tried it?